Prometheus metric for an app's version that would allow building alerts on the version change
I need to build a metric for an application's version to detect anomalies after the version change and build alerts around it.
For example, I can view the rates of error responses. There could be spikes, and it's OK. However, if the error rate spiked right after the deployment, I want to receive an alert.
With that, I need a way to track and detect the app's version.
I was planning to build a gauge with a constant value and to have labels with the version and commit's sha1. Something like this: https://www.robustperception.io/exposing-the-software-version-to-prometheus/
However, now I am struggling to build a query to detect a version change.
It'd be great to monitor the change of the label. It seems impossible. I also see that Prometheus keeps (metric_name, label) pairs as different time-series.
Is it possible? How to keep the app's version in Prometheus so I can use it in my alerts?

IIUC you're headed in the right direction but with an incorrect assumption at what you want. You can't alert (!?) on the change in a label value. Labels values are used to identify time series. You can alert on the change in a metric value. I think your solution is to alert on an increased error rate on a metric (value) and the query that represents the alert will join on your constant metric to give you the software version that's implicated.

Thanks @DazWilkin. Yesss, I really want to alert only if the spike happens right after the deployment.
I think the best I can do is to have two gauges. One gauge with a constant value and with version, commit sha1 labels. Another one (deployment_ts) with a timestamp value without labels. So that way I can use in alerts 'changes(deployment_ts[5m]) > 0' to detect if there was a change and I can retrieve version and sha1 from a gauge with a constant value.

The following query returns non-empty result whenever the application version changes, and continues returning non-empty result for 5 minutes - see 5m in square brackets:
(
  count(last_over_time(app_info[5m])) without (version)
) > 1

So this query can be appended to any alerting query via and on(instance) (...), so the resulting query will trigger (e.g. will return non-empty result) only if the original query triggers and when the version of the app has been changed during the last 5 minutes. See docs on and operator and on on() modifier.
